# Rails application fails on Heroku with MongoDB driver 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

After MongoLab force-updated my database from version 2.6 to 3.0 application crashes with exception "not authorized for query on database_name.collection_name". My application is using Mongoid gem v4.0.0 which in turn uses mongo driver version 2.4 under the hood.

From what I gathered version 3.0 has some breaking changes, so I'm not quite sure what to do here. Is there a way to make mongoid work with mongo version 3.0? Any help or advise on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Mongoid 4.0.0 uses the Moped driver, not the MongoDB driver, Mongoid 5 uses the MongoDB driver. FWIW: I have recently upgraded from mongoid 4 to mongoid 5 and the only change I needed to do was in mongoid.yml configuration... My suggestion is to try to migrate to Mongoid 5 and see if the app still behaves correctly.

Comment: @MarcoSandrini, thanks a lot, you saved the day! You can add this as the answer so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main breaking change between Mongoid 4 and Mongoid 5 is at the driver level. Mongoid 4 uses the (own) Moped driver, while Mongoid 5 uses the standard Ruby MongoDB driver.

More details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#upgrading-to-5-0-0)

My own personal experience with the upgrade was quite smooth, the only thing requiring changed being mongoid's configuration file `mongoid.yml`. But if your code was using driver-level features, or using one of the methods highlighted in the link above, it may require more changes.